# Trigger para impedir dados repetidos no ORACLE

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, dml

Opa pessoal estou tentando criar uma trigger para impedir a entrada de dados repetidos no Oracle mas não estou tendo sucesso.

Não dá para usar Constraint Unique, porque terei dados repetidos, porque é uma tabela de logs o que muda é o status que 0 é processando, 1 processado e 2 tentativa... já criado exatamente para impedir duplicidades, porém de alguma forma o usuário consegue passar... para entender ao iniciar o processo lança o status 0 e depois seta para 1, porem se em quanto o status estiver 0 e alguém tentar criar o mesmo processo para mercadoria o sistema não permitira lançando o status 2, então podem haver várias tentativas registrando o log com status 2, isso eu pego, hora inicio e fim do processo e user.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_APONTAMENTO_SERVICO_DUPLICIDADE_BLOCK
BEFORE INSERT ON EVENTO_APONTAMENTO_SERVICO FOR EACH ROW WHEN (NEW.EAPS_ID IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            IF 
                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EVENTO_APONTAMENTO_SERVICO 
                        WHERE EAPS_MERC_ID = NEW.EAPS_MERC_ID 
                            AND EAPS_ESCA_ID = NEW.EAPS_ESCA_ID 
                            AND EAPS_STATUS = 1) > 0
                            
                THEN 
            
            INSERT INTO EVENTO_APONTAMENTO_SERVICO
                (EAPS_MERC_ID, EAPS_ESCA_ID, EAPS_USUA_ID, EAPS_DTHR_INICIO, EAPS_DTHR_FIM, EAPS_OBSERVACAO, EAPS_STATUS)
                VALUES
                (NEW.EAPS_MERC_ID, NEW.EAPS_ESCA_ID ,NEW.EAPS_USUA_ID, NEW.EAPS_DTHR_INICIO, NEW.EAPS_DTHR_FIM, NEW.EAPS_OBSERVACAO, 2);
            
            END IF;

END;
```

Esse insert posso retirar e tratar ele no C#, mas queria pegar uma exceção para trata-lo

Comment: Porque precisa de uma trigger? Não pode ser uma **Constraint Unique** de chave composta? Você poderia ganhar performance também se usar Constraint

Comment: Não dá para usar Constraint Unique, porque terei dados repetidos, porque é uma tabela de logs o que muda é o status que 0 é processando, 1 processado e 2 tentativa... já criado exatamente para impedir duplicidades, porém de alguma forma o usuário consegue passar... para entender ao iniciar o processo lança o status 0 e depois seta para 1, porem se em quanto o status estiver 0 e alguém tentar criar o mesmo processo para mercadoria o sistema não permitira lançando o status 2, então podem haver várias tentativas registrando o log com status 2, isso eu pego, hora inicio e fim do processo e user.

Comment: Bastava a Unique Key (EAPS_MERC_ID,EAPS_ESCA_ID,EAPS_STATUS) mas a trigger resolve também.

Answer (score -1):

Consegui resolver, segue abaixo

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER R_APONTAMENTO_SERVICO_DUPLICIDADE_BLOCK
BEFORE INSERT ON EVENTO_APONTAMENTO_SERVICO  FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE 
    Evento varchar2(50);

    CURSOR V_AREA IS SELECT EAPS_ID FROM EVENTO_APONTAMENTO_SERVICO 
                     WHERE EAPS_MERC_ID = :NEW.EAPS_MERC_ID 
                     AND EAPS_ESCA_ID = :NEW.EAPS_ESCA_ID 
                     AND EAPS_STATUS = 0;
BEGIN
    OPEN V_AREA;
    FETCH V_AREA INTO Evento;
         
    IF V_AREA%FOUND 
        THEN 
            IF :NEW.EAPS_STATUS = 0 
            THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20500,'Mercadoria em processamento.'); 
            END IF;
    END IF;

CLOSE V_AREA;
```

END;